# WPF bind datagrid datacontext to outer property but datagridrow to his item

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datacontext

Hello I use datagrid in WPF application to display/change some data from database.
I have problem that i have binded datagrid datacontext to outer property for itemssource of observablecollection, that works perfectly, but i want to bind datagridrow backround color to his item from observablecollection, but i cannot get the item because of binded datacontext here is the code:

```
    <Grid  Height="566" Width="700" DataContext="{Binding Manager}">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Width="553">
            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,0,0">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Height="180">
                    <DataGrid Name="dataGridMain" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}" Background="White"
                              ColumnWidth="0.25*" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="dataGridMain_LoadingRow" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dataGridMain_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ???}" ></Setter>
                            </Style>

                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Manager is my own object that has observablecollection for datagrid and handles all methods, properties etc. that i need. Ive got many textoboxes and labels there, that are binded to properties of this manager, thats why it is set as "global" datacontext. I dont want to change this unless it is really necessary. So how can i get the row item property int the value={Binding ???}? 
Thanks for all your help and time.:)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have `DataGridItems` as the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`, and for each `Item` of your `DataGridItems` collection, there is a property for the `background`. So make sure that property is a `Brush` and just binding `Background` with it then.

Comment: Bolu youve undarstood perfectly and thanks very much for reply it works!:D. I thought it will not work because ive binded datacontext to other object, but it seems it doesnt matter what is datacontext of datagrid, for row it will be always his item. Thanks for much:) All that i need now is find out how to make datagrid to not load color property as column:D

Comment: Just set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false and define your `DataGrid.Columns` manually in your XAML. Or you can handle `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx

Comment: I have already handled `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event so I added it there and it works. Thanks very much for your very usefull advices:)